# How do I access Google Playstore API to get reviews of our app using Python script?

Tags: python, android, automation, google-play-services, google-reviews

I have a service account and private key generated for the account with the app.

testxyz.json - contains the private key and service account information.

Here's the script:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import ssl
import json

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('testxyz.json',scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])


http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)
print(service)

package_name = "xtestx"
reviews_resource = service.reviews()
print(reviews_resource)
reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name,maxResults=100).execute()
reviews_list = reviews_page["reviews"]

infinite_loop_canary = 100
while "tokenPagination" in reviews_page:
    reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name,maxResults=100).execute()
    token=reviews_page["tokenPagination"]["nextPageToken"],
    maxResults=100).execute()
    reviews_list.extend(reviews_page["reviews"])
    infinite_loop_canary -= 1
    if infinite_loop_canary < 0:
        break
```

The line in the script - reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name,maxResults=100).execute()- is throwing "The caller does not have permission"

I am not exactly sure what needs to be done. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the answer here since it took quite some time for me to figure this out, maybe it'll help someone else.

What you need before:

1. Service account from https://console.developers.google.com
2. A private key for the SA. (used .p12 file)
3. In Play Console, we need to grant access to this SA from Developer account -> API access.
4. Once we click on Grant Access(from step 3), we have Permissions dialog - enable "Reply to reviews" for the required apps.

   ```
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    import httplib2
    from oauth2client import client
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = ('associated_service_email_address_goes_here')

    #this is the private key file
    key = 'xxx.p12' 
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'

    credentials= ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key,
    scopes=[scope])

    package_name = "xtestx"

    try:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)

        reviews_resource = service.reviews()
        print(reviews_resource)
        reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name,maxResults=100).execute()
        reviews_list = reviews_page["reviews"]
    except Exception as e:
        ...
   ```

The permissions created the issue from me.